# How to transfer a logistic regression model from r to Excel

Tags: r, excel

Recently I have been working in R to create a logistic regression model to predict the chance of a loan being repaid.

I would like to be able to transfer my model to Excel to allow my co-workers who know nothing about R to use it. I have tried using the coefficients returned from the summary function but they provide  answers far outside of 0 and 1.

How can I transfer my regression model to Excel?

Answer (score 1):

The output of a logistic regression model is a log-odds. You would need to take the value from the equations and convert it to a probability between 0 and 1 e.g. `1/(1+exp(-x))`

Comment: thank you for the help exactly what i was looking for!